# Alamofire extension for showing photos in collection view (SWIFT 2.0)

Tags: swift2, alamofire

Hello I need a little help with this code. I followed the example in this link
http://www.raywenderlich.com/85080/beginning-alamofire-tutorial

My code in swift 1.x was and It worked perfectly

```
extension Alamofire.Request {
    class func imageResponseSerializer() -> Serializer {
        return { request, response, data in
            if data == nil {
                return (nil, nil)
            }

            let image = UIImage(data: data!, scale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

            return (image, nil)
        }
    }

    func responseImage(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, UIImage?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
        return response(serializer: Request.imageResponseSerializer(), completionHandler: { (request, response, image, error) in
            completionHandler(request, response, image as? UIImage, error)
        })
    }
}
```

But then I migrated to Swift 2.0 and I found on the Internet another code for this, because the first one does not work anymore.

```
extension Alamofire.Request {
    class func imageResponseSerializer() -> GenericResponseSerializer<UIImage> {
        return GenericResponseSerializer { request, response, data in
            if data == nil {
                return (nil, nil)
            }

            let image = UIImage(data: data!, scale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

            return (image, nil)
        }
    }

    public func responseImage(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
        return response(serializer: Request.responseDataSerializer(), completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}

struct GenericResponseSerializer<T> : ResponseSerializer {
    typealias SerializedObject = T
    var serializeResponse: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, NSData?) -> (T?, NSError?)
    init(serializeResponse: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, NSData?) -> (T?, NSError?))
}
```

Neither of them work now in Swift 2.0, and for the last code I get these errors:

- Reference of Generic type 'ResponseSerializer' required arguments in <...> (line *struct GenericResponseSerializer : ResponseSerializer {*)
- Initializer requires a body. (line *init(serializeResponse: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, NSData?) -> (T?, NSError?))*)
- Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSHTTPURLResponse?' (line *return response(serializer: Request.responseDataSerializer(), completionHandler: completionHandler)*)

The way I call it for showing an image on a collection view is:

```
cell.request = Alamofire.request(.GET, imageURL!).responseImage() {
    (request, _, image, error) in
    if error == nil && image != nil {
        if request.URL == cell.request?.request!.URL {
            cell.firstphoto.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

I already upgraded Alamofire to the last version. (Yesterday)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alamofire 2.0 is redesigned, so take a look here: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%202.0%20Migration%20Guide.md

Your code would look something like this:

```
cell.request = Alamofire.request(.GET, imageURL!)
         .responseData { request, _, result in
        if let error = result.error as? NSError {
          //handle error
          return
        }else{

         //Check if image is correct
         //result.value
        }
    }
```

It seems that `.responseImage` no longer exists.

Comment: Thanks! With the new Alamofire there is no need for the extension. I will edit my post with the final code because I did some modifications.